# How does IFS split a string in shell

Tags: shell, ifs

I change IFS to `:`

When I use the string "abc:xyz:jkl" directly, the for loop only iterates once. The string is not split.

```
IFS=:
for i in abc:xyz:jkl
do
    echo $i
done
```

But when I store the value in a variable, the string is split and the loop iterates three times.

```
IFS=:
var="abc:xyz:jkl"
for i in $var
do
    echo $i
done
```

Another similar question is, **when I have the IFS as default**, `for i in "abc xyz jkl"` and `var="abc xyz jkl; for i in $var"` also run differently.